# Is it possible to add "unread" to the sort functions of Superuser?

Tags: feature-request

I read most posts for educational purposes. It would be very helpful if there was an unread sort function.

Regards,

Comment: You might want to propose this at Meta.SO instead, although I have the believe that there isn't much interest in this.

Comment: @TomWij If required moderators can migrate question to Meta SO if there is enough support for a future, no need to repost it there.

Comment: @Diago: Well, I was thinking the question here could then be deleted. But from my point of view I can't just do a close vote or flag as I'm unsure about the use of migrating it there. But yeah, I might have asked if he wants migration instead, thanks. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "undread"? Meaning you haven't read it or nobody's read it?

Comment: I mean unread by me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just sort the questions by [newest first](https://meta.superuser.com/questions?sort=newest) and then read them starting from the oldest one?

You have to apply a "read now or bookmark for later" policy, this will allow you to just keep bookmarking.

That way, you don't have to track if you have read an individual question;
instead, you just need to track what the last question vaù and process all newer questions. Those you haven't read are bookmarked. :-)

Comment: I do use "newest 1st". I'll accept this and we can all move on. Thanks everyone.